# Spring cloud function send image / bytes

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-function

I want to receive and send back an image file using [Spring Cloud Function Web](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function).
Receiving works fine, but not sending. Somehow only JSON is delivered.
I am using Spring Boot 3.0.0 with Spring Cloud 2022.0.0.

Here is my Kotlin source code:

```
// you can call this with POST http://localhost:8080/kotlinByteConsumer sending the file as form-data 
 @Bean
    fun kotlinByteConsumer(): (MultipartFile) -> Message<ByteArray> {
        return {
            // save file to disc
            val receivedFile = File("${it.originalFilename}")
            receivedFile.writeBytes(it.bytes)

            // send file back
            MessageBuilder
              .withPayload(receivedFile.readBytes())
              .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
              .build()
        }
    }
```

[image: postman test request with response]

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to configure the JSON Mapper to not fail on binary transfer:

```
@Configuration
class JSONConfig() {

    @Bean
    fun getObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper{
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
        return mapper
    }

}
```

With this you can create the function:

```
@Bean
    fun getUserPicture(): () -> Message<InputStreamResource> {
        return {
            val file = File("avatar_dummy.jpg")
            val resource = InputStreamResource(file.inputStream())

            MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(resource)
                .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    ContentDisposition.attachment().filename(file.name).build()
                        .toString()
                )
                .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
                .build()
        }
    }
```